# How to create external, filesystem, read-only entrypoint for process internal memory?

Tags: linux, memory

Target platform is **GNU/Linux**.

---

Let's say I have:

```
void *p
```

I want to be create entrypoint for that internal memory in filesystem like:

```
/tmp/my_entry_point
```

And I'd like to be able to read that memory **from within another proccess**.

```
fd = open("/tmp/my_entry_point", ...)
read(fd, ...)
```

Is it possible to create and read such pseudo-device?

Answer (score 6):

It actually sounds like you're describing POSIX shared memory.

Here is a quick pair of example programs to show how it works. On my system, the files get created in /run/shm (which is a tmpfs). Other systems use /dev/shm. Your program doesn't need to care, `shm_open` takes care of that.

### server.c:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int fd;
    long pagesize;
    char *region;

    if (-1 == (pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE))) {
        perror("sysconf _SC_PAGE_SIZE");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (-1 == (fd = shm_open("/some-name", O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_EXCL, 0640))) {
        perror("shm_open");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (-1 == ftruncate(fd, pagesize)) {
        perror("ftruncate");
        shm_unlink("/some-name");
        exit(1);
    }

    region = mmap(NULL, pagesize, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (!region) {
        perror("mmap");
        shm_unlink("/some-name");
        exit(1);
    }

    // PAGESIZE is guaranteed to be at least 1, so this is safe.
    region[0] = 'a';

    sleep(60);

    shm_unlink("/some-name");
}
```

### client.c

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int fd;
    long pagesize;
    char *region;

    if (-1 == (pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE))) {
        perror("sysconf _SC_PAGE_SIZE");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (-1 == (fd = shm_open("/some-name", O_RDONLY, 0640))) {
        perror("shm_open");
        exit(1);
    }

    region = mmap(NULL, pagesize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (!region) {
        perror("mmap");
        shm_unlink("/some-name");
        exit(1);
    }

    // PAGESIZE is guaranteed to be at least 1, so this is safe.
    printf("The character is '%c'\n", region[0]);
}
```

### Makefile

```make
LDFLAGS += -lrt

all: server client
```

Comment: POSIX shared memory may have the effect the questioner wants, but he asked for the resulting object to appear in the filesystem. The `name` parameter for `shm_open(2)` does not correspond to any filesystem entry. Indeed, on Linux, it cannot have embedded slashes, so it cannot be called `/tmp/my_entry_point`, as the questioner specified. Again, it may be a matter of [overspecification](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/03/a-parable.aspx) in the question, but the point needs to be raised.

Comment: @WarrenYoung that is definitely true, it's just a token that can be passed to another call to shm_open. Of course, on Linux, it is a file (as I mentioned), but generally isn't in /tmp. But yeah, I've assumed the question is slightly overspecified.